# Overhang notification at bottom of the screen

Tags: jquery, css

I am using [overhang](https://github.com/paulkr/overHang.js/) to display a notification whenever user lands on my website. The notification appears from top of my screen and remains there when I scroll down. I want the same functionality but at the bottom of the screen. Basically, I want the notification to appear at the bottom of the screen rather than top and then remain there even if I scroll down/top. How can I do that?

The code for overhang is as follows:

```
$("body").overhang({
  custom: true,
  message: "Upcoming event",
  closeConfirm: true
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `overhang.min.css` you'll find

```
.overhang,.overhang-overlay{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0}
```

If you replace `top:0;` by `bottom:0;` it should be fixed at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 2):

***Paul*** answer should work if you can modify `overhang` CSS file. If you can't, just override that style in your custom CSS, something like:

```
body .overhang,
body .overhang-overlay {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

`body` is added to make the rule more accurate so it overrides styles from `overhang.css` without using unnecessary `!import` directives.

Comment: Valid comment. Just for explanation: `body` is added to the rules here to make sure these rules overwrite the original css of overhang.js independent of load order of css files.

Comment: Good note, Paul. I've added clarification to my post. Thanks for a comment!