# Overhang js notification with an offset from top to be under fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, css

I am using [Overhang](https://paulkr.github.io/overhang.js/) to display a notification on my main page, and I would like to have an offset from the top, since I am using Bootstrap with a fixed navbar and just want the Overhang message below the navbar.

I found this question:
[Overhang notification at bottom of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350782/overhang-notification-at-bottom-of-the-screen)

Which discusses changing the CSS for Overhang, and tried to add **top:10** to the CSS, however then the whole Overhang notification disappears. Basically for every number other than zero.

```
.overhang-overlay{position:fixed;top:10;left:0;right:0}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or can this be because of Bootstrap?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not able to override the property.

you can do something like:

```
body .overhang,
body .overhang-overlay {
    top: 10;
}
```

or you can simply use `!important` to make sure it overrides the default property

```
.overhang-overlay {
    top: 10 !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @saurabh, tried both. Unfortunately !important produces the same effect: the overhang notification simply disappears if the top (or bottom) property is not zero. The first code does not seem to do anything, in that case the notification appears at the top, covering the navbar.